# Open source web development framework

Tags: open-source, web

I am a C++ developer. I want to develop a website in which I plan to put

1. User accounts
2. User groups
3. Alerts based on user preferences

Can anybody suggest the best open source framework that I can use to create this website. I hope that the framework would provide basic underlying infrastructer like session management etc. In short what would you suggest to create such a website?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you looking for a C++ framework? I've never heard of one, and I wouldn't expect many to be out there. C++ isn't a common language of choice for web development.

Comment: No I am not looking for any C++ framework. I know there aren't any. I mentioned this so that if somebody can suggest some framework where the underlying language is similar or closer to C++ that would help me develop it quickly. But I realize that I should have mentioned that in the question though.

Comment: You might want to make this community wiki. It seems somewhat subjective and argumentative.

Comment: PHP is close to C / C++, you could easily work with that.

Answer (score 3):

I'm a mainly a PHP web developper, so I will talk about php framework.
I like [expressionengine](https://expressionengine.com) as it provide a fully functional backend with user/group management and is easily extendable (a lot of plugins exists). With it you juste have to program the public interface and you can use the backend to manage stuff.

If you want to do it your own way, you can try Symfony, [code igniter](http://codeigniter.com/) (expression engine is build using code igniter) or [Zend Framework](http://framework.zend.com/). Both provide similar tools (MVC, DB Abstraction, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

i'm mainly a java developer, so i'll recommend you a .. Python framework ;)

for your use case, i can highly recommend [Django](http://www.djangoproject.com/)

it has a built-in [auth system](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/) which consists of:

- Users
- Permissions
- Groups

also important for your use case: you can easily [extend the built-in User model](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#storing-additional-information-about-users) to also include the user's preferences.

it's also very easy to get started.

some other nice features:

- [dynamic admin interface](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/overview/#a-dynamic-admin-interface-it-s-not-just-scaffolding-it-s-the-whole-house) (~ scaffolding)
- flexible templating system
- rapid development
- it comes with an [object-relational mapper](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/overview/#design-your-model) in which you describe your database layout in Python code (no need to write SQL yourself)
- MVC-like
- open source of course

Answer (score 0):

I'm fond of [Catalyst](http://www.catalystframework.org/), it has an excellent plugin system which includes things like [Catalyst::ActionRole::ACL](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Catalyst::ActionRole::ACL) (which should cover your user groups requirement)

Answer (score 0):

Though the framework is not actually open source, I would suggest working with the .Net framework. You don't have to shell out for Microsoft's IDE - check out [Sharp Develop](http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SD/) for instance...